# Is lazy loading a clever way of keeping internal links to a minimum?

Tags: seo, links, ajax

I am working on the development of a news website where the front page has a very basic design which shows the latest 3 news and latest 3 featured posts of the website's main categories(six in all) in a format similar to the below:

```
Category #1 Name                                 Category #1 Name
Category #1 Latest Post #1                       Category #1 Featured Post #1
Category #1 Latest Post #2                       Category #1 Featured Post #2
Category #1 Latest Post #3                       Category #1 Featured Post #3
```

My concern is that the client wants the above information to also be available in the header via a mega menu(same, exact logic as http://www.ebay.com when you hover on Motors at the top).

Now to keep the number of internal links to a minimum and knowing that all links in the mega menu **are already available elsewhere in the website**, I was thinking of opting for a lazy loading approach for the mega menu's links, a total of 60 links.

Meaning that that the links are not available inside the HTML when the page loads but are requested via an Ajax call with the html injected in a DIV element after the mega menu html is retrieved.

As I of course don't want Google to crawl the mega menu links, is this a clever approach to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your concern, pages with many links are not necessarily considered spammy (says [Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/how-many-links-per-page/)).

Lazy loading your links is not going to solve your issue, since Google is now capable of executing Javascript. It would find about your mega menu links. So don't bother the hassle if that is your only intent.

If you don't want Google to crawl the mega menu links, just mark them as `nofollow`. That's enough.

Comment: Oh, that's great. So just to confirm, there is no need for javascript and the lazy loading and ALL the links inside the mega menu - since they are all available elsewhere - will be set with the nofollow tag, correct?

Comment: Yes, not need for lazy loading. Moreover, 60 links in the mega menu is not an issue. So regarding indexing, I personally would not mark them as nofollow to let Google find about your pages. I would also implement a sitemap.xml containing the URL of all your pages.

Comment: Good answer apart from the last line. Adding nofollow to internal links will only harm your site, not improve anything. See https://youtube.com/watch?v=bVOOB_Q0MZY